# How to find probability after finding the CDF of a max?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I have the pdf:

$$ f(x)=10x^9, 0 < x < 1$$

Assuming independence, let *Y*=max(X<sub>1</sub>,...X<sub>8</sub>).

Find the cdf for Y:
I found this to be y<sup>80</sup>

Now I have  to find P(.9999 < *Y* < 1)

I thought this would be:
 P(.9999 < *Y* < 1)=
P(.9999 < *X<sub>1</sub>* < 1)*...*P(.9999 < *X<sub>8</sub>* < 1)
=[P(.9999 < *X1* < 1)]<sup>8</sup>
 $$(\int_.9999^1 10x^9 dx)^8$$

but that turns out to be a very small number, so I think I did something wrong...

Comment: That is the probability all the values, including the *minimum*, are between $0.9999$ and $1$.

Comment: So would I need to use negation and do 1 minus the probability of what I already have found?

Comment: Not quite: that would give you the probability not all the values are between $0.9999$ and $1$.  I suspect you want not all the values to be between $0$ and $0.9999$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Would this question be the same as the probability that X > .9999 and X <1? Is that where the minimum would come into this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- What is the probability $0 \le X_1 \le 0.9999$?
- What is the probability $0 \le X_i \le 0.9999$ for all $i$?
- What is the probability $0 \le Y \le 0.9999$?
- What is the probability $0.9999 \lt Y \lt 1$?

Comment: Would it be correct to use 1-P(0≤Y≤0.9999)?
Wouldn't that give me all of the values between .9999 and 1?

Comment: @MarissaFarina: Yes